# Bootstrap Hide Modal After Delay

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to hide a bootstrap modal after a delay (~3 seconds).  I tried the following, none of which had any visible effect:

```js
 $(".embedModal").delay(3000).modal('hide');
 setTimeout($('.embedModal').modal('hide'),3000);
```

How can I add a short delay before hiding the modal?

Answer (score 16):

Try wrapping the call to modal in a function.

```
setTimeout(function() { $('.embedModal').modal('hide'); }, 3000);
```

Comment: this doesn't work as desired if you manually hide the modal and reopen it within 3 seconds

Comment: how to do without jquery , just by html and class use ?